# Tomcat duplicate httpHeaderSecurity running from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat8

I am running Tomcat v8.0 from inside Eclipse. I am trying to open url from the same site in an iFrame. Originally I was getting a message that said X-Frame-Options was set to DENY. So I added the following in the Tomcat

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
        <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But now when I try to load the iFrame, it tells me "Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/hub/warehouses' in a frame because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('SAMEORIGIN, DENY'). Falling back to 'deny'."

I cannot find any place in the workspace that has the default DENY.

How can I resolve this?